# Why is file_put_contents() sometimes throwing a "No error" error?

Tags: php, nginx, warnings, file-put-contents

Why does this code sometimes give a `No such file or directory` warning but other times a `No error` warning;

```
<?php

file_put_contents('*bad*', 'hello world');    // Trigger illegal filename.

?>
```

Usually gives this error warning;

```
Warning: file_put_contents(*bad*): failed to open stream: No such file
or directory in C:\root\noerror.php on line 3
```

but if I wait a minute and run it again, sometimes it says this instead;

```
Warning: file_put_contents(*bad*): failed to open stream: No error in
C:\root\noerror.php on line 3
```

Any ideas?

I'm using Windows 7, PHP 5.5.11 and nginx 1.4.6. In my php.ini I've got;

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = On
html_errors = On
error_log = php_errors.log
```

Which I think are just the normal default development error settings except for `error_log`.

The same thing happens in the log file - sometimes it says `No such file or directory` other times it says `No error`;

```
[11-Jan-2017 12:29:25 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(*bad*): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\root\noerror.php on line 3
[11-Jan-2017 12:29:26 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(*bad*): failed to open stream: No error in C:\root\noerror.php on line 3
```

Comment: @anant, Nigel is asking why the different errors appear. The one you posted as a duplicate was only asking how to fix the error.

Comment: @nigel, have you checked the php error log for clues?

Comment: @raphael75 At the end of my question there's an extract from the error log.

Comment: As it uses fopen() it may collide using file locking.

Comment: Interestingly this creates the file properly on Linux (PHP 7.0.15). This is probably an issue with how Windows handles filenames. May I suggest you submit a bug report: https://bugs.php.net/report.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to give full access to user on the folder where is *bad* located

- mouse right click ->properties
  -Security ->Edit
  -select Everyone and save